# Can I trace consuming of events in RxJava Subscriber?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I would like to trace when subscriber started consume events and when finished.
Is there any generic way which will work for all Observables/Subscribers?

Comment: There is a `onSubscribe(disposable)` method will be called once Observable starting emit events. And  when `onComplete()`/`onError` being called  means it terminated.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for generic solution like RxJavaHooks. So I don't need access to each observable. It should work like a spy for any observable in current jvm instance.

Comment: I see. You could use `setOnObservableSubscribe` in RxJavaPlugin.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how to use it. This hook works only for 'subscribe' event. I need trace when subscriber started to consume events and when finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it for 1.x or 2.x? For 2.x it can become quite convoluted because all the internal protocols have to be considered to not accidentally de-optimize your flows.

Otherwise, it can be as simple as writing a `Observer` that is shimmed between the real `Observer` and the operator:

```
import io.reactivex.Observer;

RxJavaPlugins.setOnObservableSubscribe((observable, observer) -> {
    if (!observable.getClass().getName().toLowerCase().contains("map")) {
        return observer;
    }

    System.out.println("Started");

    class SignalTracker implements Observer<Object>, Disposable {
        Disposable upstream;
        @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            upstream = d;
            // write the code here that has to react to establishing the subscription
            observer.onSubscribe(this);
        }
        @Override public void onNext(Object o) {
            // handle onNext before or aftern notifying the downstream
            observer.onNext(o);
        }
        @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
            // handle onError
            observer.onError(t);
        }
        @Override public void onComplete() {
            // handle onComplete
            System.out.println("Completed");
            observer.onComplete();
        }
        @Override public void dispose() {
            // handle dispose
            upstream.dispose();
        }
        @Override public boolean isDisposed() {
            return upstream.isDisposed();
        }
    }
    return new SignalTracker();
  });

  Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.range(1, 5)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .map(integer -> {
        try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return integer * 3;
      });

  observable.subscribe(System.out::println);

  Thread.sleep(6000L);
```

Prints:

```
Started
3
6
9
12
15
Completed
```

**Edit:** The RxJava 1 version needs a bit more lambdas but doable:

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnObservableStart((observable, onSubscribe) -> {
    if (!onSubscribe.getClass().getName().toLowerCase().contains("map")) {
        return onSubscribe;
    }

    System.out.println("Started");

    return (Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>)observer -> {
        class SignalTracker extends Subscriber<Object> {
            @Override public void onNext(Object o) {
                // handle onNext before or aftern notifying the downstream
                observer.onNext(o);
            }
            @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
                // handle onError
                observer.onError(t);
            }
            @Override public void onCompleted() {
                // handle onComplete
                System.out.println("Completed");
                observer.onCompleted();
            }
            @Override public void setProducer(Producer p) {
                observer.setProducer(p);
            }
        }
        SignalTracker t = new SignalTracker()
        observer.add(t);
        onSubscribe.call(t);
    };
  });

  Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.range(1, 5)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
      .map(integer -> {
        try {
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return integer * 3;
      });

  observable.subscribe(System.out::println);

  Thread.sleep(6000L);
```

Comment: I added example in the description. This solution doesn't work for it.

Comment: "Completed" is printed before subscriber finished processing of all events.

Comment: The hook adds tracking to all operators: range, subscribeOn, observeOn, map thus you get 4 "started". Also if you'd sleep for 6 seconds, you could see 4 completed.

Comment: @smalafeev that's exactly why I told you need make a condition for your observable. Every operator will generate a new Observable from it, for ex: ObservableMap. Your upstream observable received onComplete event but your downstream have not. So you see the onComplete before your map.

Comment: Now I have a problem to build a chain. I cannot find relations between generated observables.